# Moment.js startOf with format

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js as follows:

```
from_moment = moment(e.date).startOf('month');
```

given my date object this correctly gives me:

```
Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

However this is not in the format that I require, so I tried:

```
from_moment = moment(e.date).startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

the output of this is:

```
2019-02-01 12:00:00
```

The format is correct but I don't understand why 12 hours have been added and I now have midday on the first day of the month?

Comment: Read the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/. Lowercase h is 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using 12-hour time. If you format the time with `HH:mm:ss` instead you'll get 24-hour time.

```js
// HH = 24 hour time
moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// "2019-07-01 00:00:00"

// hh is 12 hour time, adding "a" to the end will show am/pm
moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a');
// "2019-07-01 12:00:00 am"
```

Comment: whoops sorry, fixing - I had it correct in the code but not the comment. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: what if i want to use .fromNow() with formating so it would be like this `moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a').fromNow()`, but i get an error

Comment: Switch it to `.fromNow().format()` You can only call `fromNow()` on a moment object. When you call `.format()` the moment object is converted to a string.